# Ubuntu 20.04 not shutting down/restarting, just freezing on the desktop screen

Tags: 20.04, shutdown, reboot

I upgraded my system to Ubuntu 20.04 and since then I've had this problem: my system does not shut down or restart (either from the desktop or the terminal), instead the screen just freezes on the desktop screen.

I do not have much experience with Linux, so if anyone knows how to solve this problem, please give me detailed instructions on how to fix it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do your shutdown command, then wait 35 minutes. Some part of shutting down your system has hung, with a 30 minute timeout. In a terminal window, the command `sudo journalctl -b -1 -e` will show you the end of the previous boot's logs. Check for "timeout" messages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

Comment: This question is specifically about freezing on shutdown, not about freezing in general